# Web service call from different machines

Tags: c#, web-services

I have a web service function call in my tool. The web service is a internet URL.

When I run the tool in a machine in a environment, the web service function is working fine with proper response.

But when I run the tool in a machine in other environment, the web service function is not working and gives below  error.

> WebException : The request failed with an empty response. WebException
>   stack trace :    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage
>   message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean
>   asyncCall)    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String
>   methodName, Object[] parameters)    at

Comment: This is a low quality question, we can only guess, and mine is firewall

Comment: Try pinging the url host name from the environment machine and see if you are getting the response

Comment: the error could be due to a different IE on the two machines.  I would start by using a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare the request headers on working and non work machines.  I would also delete cookies in working machine and see if the code still works.  Often after you modify code the cookies are still installed and the code works until the cookies are deleted.  The the working machine stops working.